# Let $f:z \to z^n$. What's the image of $f[g]$ in $H_1(S^1)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology

Let $f:S^1 \to S^1$ by $f:z \mapsto z^n$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'd like to know what the image of $f_*(g)$, where $g$ is the generator of $H_1(S^1)$.

I know that $H_1(S^1)$ is generated by the class of the map $t \mapsto e^{2\pi i t}.$ If I compose this map with $f, \ $ I get the map: $ \ t \mapsto e^{2\pi i n t}.$ Let's call this generator $g$.Thus it seems like $f_*(g)=ng$.

My idea is this: consider the following element of $C_2(S^1): (s,t) \mapsto e^{2\pi i n t}+ne^{2\pi i s}.$ If apply the differential to this element, which we may call $\varepsilon$, we should get:
$$\partial(\varepsilon)=e^{2\pi i n t}+n*1-ne^{2\pi i t}-1, $$ where by $1$ I mean constant the map $\Delta^1 \to \{1\} \subseteq S^1$. Since $[1]=0$, and $[\partial(\varepsilon)]=0, \ $ we have:

$0=[\partial (\varepsilon)]=[e^{2\pi i n t}+n*\boldsymbol{1}-ne^{2\pi i t}-\boldsymbol{1}]=[e^{2\pi i n t}]-n[e^{2\pi i  t}] $ thus $[e^{2\pi i n t}]=n[e^{2\pi i  t}]$ as requested.

Comment: What kind of homology are you working with?

Comment: @RobArthan singular homology

Comment: What is your definition of $\Delta^2$? The span of $0,e_1, e_2$ in $\mathbb R^2$? Or the span of $e_1,e_2,e_3$ in  $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: I see. Your formula for a $2$-cell suggests you are using cubes rather than simplices to define singular homology. Is that right?

Comment: PS: I meant "$2$-chain" not "$2$-cell".

Comment: @PaulFrost $\Delta^2=\{(s,t,u) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}: s+t+u=1\}$

Comment: @RobArthan They should be the same really, cause I can send $(s,t,1-s-t)\mapsto (s,t)$, right?

Comment: @Alessandro So it is the span of $e_1,e_2,e_3$ in $\mathbb R^3$. You should clarify this in your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost it is not span$(e_1,e_2e_3)$ because we need $s, t, u$ to be positive and they need to sum up to $1$. But since $u=1-s-t$ , we can kinda ignore $u$ as it is uniquely determined by the other $2$.

Comment: @Alessandro Sorry, I meant the convex hull ;-)

Comment: Your question suggests that you are uncertain whether your solution is correct. At which step do you have doubts?

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm not sure whether I applied the differential map correctly.

Comment: Your element of $C_2(S^1)$ cannot be a singular $2$-simplex $\Delta^2 \to S^1$ because in $S^1$ there is no meaning of $e^{2\pi i n t}+ne^{2\pi i s}$. So do you mean some $2$-chain of the form $\sigma + n\tau$ with singular $2$-simplices $\sigma, \tau$? If yes, you should properly define it.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes I meant a chain, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does not work. Let us do it formally.

We write the points of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ in the form of tuples $(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$. Define the standard $n$-simplex as
$$\Delta^n = \left\{(t_0,\ldots,t_n) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid t_j \ge 0, \sum_{j=0]}^n t_j = 1 \right\} .$$
It is nothing else than the convex hull of the $n+1$ standard basis vectors $e_0,\ldots,e_n$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. The $1$-simplex $\Delta^1$ is usually identified with $I$ via $h : I \to \Delta^1, h(t) = (t,1-t)$. Doing so, $\phi : \Delta^1 \to X$ can be replaced by $\phi  h : I \to X$ ("alternative form of singular $1$-simplices").

Define $\gamma_n : \Delta^1 \to S^1, \gamma_n(t_0, t_1) = e^{2\pi i n t_0}$. In alternative form it is $\gamma_n : I \to S^1, \gamma(t) = e^{2\pi in  t}$. The generator of $H_1(S^1)$ is represented by $\gamma_1$.

To compute the boundary of a singular $2$-simplex $\sigma$ we need the three face embeddings $d_k : \Delta^1 \to \Delta^2$ given by $d_0(t_0,t_1) = (0,t_0,t_1), d_1(t_0,t_1) = (t_0,0,t_1), d_2(t_0,t_1) = (t_0,t_1,0)$. Then

$$\partial \sigma = \sigma d_0 - \sigma d_1 + \sigma d_2 .$$

Replacing $\Delta^1$ as above by $I$, we get face embeddings $d_k : I \to \Delta^2$ given by $d_0(t) = (0,t,1-t), d_1(t) = (t,0,1-t), d_2(t) = (t,1-t,0)$. The path $d_0$ parameterizes the line segment $[e_2,e_1]$ in direction from $e_2$ to $e_1$, $d_1$ parameterizes the line segment $[e_2,e_0]$ in direction from $e_2$ to $e_0$ and $d_2$ parameterizes the line segment $[e_1,e_0]$ in direction from $e_1$ to $e_0$.

Let us define a singular $2$-simplex by $\alpha_{n,j}(t_0,t_1,t_2) = e^{2\pi i nt_j}$. We get
$$\partial \alpha_{n,0} = 1 - \gamma_n + \gamma_n  = 1,$$
$$\partial \alpha_{n,1} = \gamma_n - 1 + \gamma_{-n} , $$
$$\partial \alpha_{n,2} = \gamma_{-n} - \gamma_{-n} + 1 = 1. $$

This shows that none of the $2$-chains $\alpha_{n,j} \pm n\alpha_{1,k}$ gives any reasonable relation between $\gamma_n$ and $n \gamma_1$. In your question you used $\alpha_{n,0} + n\alpha_{1,1}$.

So what can be done? Actually you should use the *Hurewicz homomorphism*
$$h : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to H_1(X)$$
which assigns to each path homotopy class $[\gamma] \in  \pi_1(X,x_0)$ the homology class $[\gamma] \in H_1(X)$. Note that if $\gamma$ is a closed path, then $\gamma$ is a $1$-cycle. You have to do some checkings:

1. Path homotopic closed paths are homologous when regarded as $1$-cycles.
2. A composition $\gamma_1 * \gamma_2$ of closed paths is homologous to the sum-$1$-cycle $\gamma_1 + \gamma_2$.

You can find this in most textbook on algebraic topology.